# are infected files automatically quaranteened or removed in Clam TK?

Tags: clamav, clamtk

after Clam TK scan I get this in report .

How to quaranteen or delete  files ?

```
/home/joso/.config/libreoffice/4/user/basic/Standard/Module1.xba: PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2 FOUND
/home/joso/.cache/mozilla/firefox/uot09tm7.default-release/cache2/entries/F3E66A595E83D041E1FAA753D6891C1F834D999D: PUA.Win.Exploit.CVE_2012_1461-1 FOUND
/home/joso/.cache/mozilla/firefox/uot09tm7.default-release/cache2/entries/192B6C604083F2F8CA5C3B256F6503F2EED6C356: PUA.Win.Exploit.CVE_2012_1461-1 FOUND
/home/joso/.cache/mozilla/firefox/uot09tm7.default-release/cache2/entries/8692CD48ACD5FEF8A15738DF2967BB8F24774B39: PUA.Win.Exploit.CVE_2012_1461-1 FOUND
/home/joso/.cache/mozilla/firefox/uot09tm7.default-release/cache2/entries/202830B1AEC4163D9E44121DFE05997DDB9D0F5C: PUA.Win.Exploit.CVE_2012_1461-1 FOUND
/home/joso/.cache/mozilla/firefox/uot09tm7.default-release/cache2/entries/E1FB319332D07B90FF6D8C61A4A824C51FDC2CA6: PUA.Win.Exploit.CVE_2012_1461-1 FOUND
/home/joso/.cache/mozilla/firefox/uot09tm7.default-release/cache2/entries/9775D2629CA01D3822064AF3C63963D598577D13: PUA.Win.Exploit.CVE_2012_1461-1 FOUND
/home/joso/.cache/mozilla/firefox/uot09tm7.default-release/cache2/entries/A7409BF7EDF17C8DA0E211C22DF4F32DC44CB3ED: PUA.Win.Exploit.CVE_2012_1461-1 FOUND
/home/joso/.cache/mozilla/firefox/uot09tm7.default-release/cache2/entries/C9D74473D012C2C11830F414ABC36133F8426BEB: PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1 FOUND
/home/joso/.cache/mozilla/firefox/uot09tm7.default-release/cache2/entries/4183DCD90871653B99882B62E42BF38DD2E6E29C: PUA.Win.Exploit.CVE_2012_1461-1 FOUND
/home/joso/.cache/mozilla/firefox/uot09tm7.default-release/cache2/entries/82E1AC12C9A48FE247184A40752A0250A3607DA2: PUA.Win.Exploit.CVE_2012_1461-1 FOUND
/home/joso/.cache/mozilla/firefox/uot09tm7.default-release/cache2/entries/C435B0454EE68144D531CA47C649C3B2F6121C46: PUA.Win.Exploit.CVE_2012_1461-1 FOUND
/home/joso/.cache/mozilla/firefox/uot09tm7.default-release/cache2/entries/124AE7BE33894E844BAE0326EDF3D2AF85C31650: PUA.Win.Exploit.CVE_2012_1461-1 FOUND
/home/joso/.cache/mozilla/firefox/uot09tm7.default-release/cache2/entries/1081E83D3B4F913688A9A155D4CC63B2759D0A74: PUA.Win.Exploit.CVE_2012_1461-1 FOUND
/home/joso/.cache/mozilla/firefox/uot09tm7.default-release/cache2/entries/ACF2C449528BD44519F66584C340C1248F6208F7: PUA.Win.Exploit.CVE_2012_1461-1 FOUND
/home/joso/.mozilla/firefox/uot09tm7.default-release/extensions/support@lastpass.com.xpi: PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1 FOUND
/home/joso/MEGA/.debris/2019-10-03/2019-08-28_12-56-53-131/net.sourceforge.opencamera.apk: PUA.Andr.Adware.Ewind-6878615-0 FOUND
/home/joso/MEGA/.debris/2019-10-03/2019-08-28_12-56-53-131/com.google.android.music.apk: PUA.Andr.Adware.Revmob-6803898-0 FOUND
/home/joso/MEGA/.debris/2019-10-03/2019-08-28_12-56-53-131/hr.tele2.support.apk: PUA.Andr.Trojan.Mobidash-6840972-0 FOUND
/home/joso/MEGA/.debris/2019-10-03/2019-08-28_12-56-53-131/ch.protonmail.android.apk: PUA.Andr.Adware.Domob-6888036-0 FOUND
/home/joso/MEGA/.debris/2019-10-03/2019-08-28_12-56-53-131/com.lastpass.lpandroid.apk: PUA.Andr.Trojan.Mobidash-6840972-0 FOUND
/home/joso/MEGA/.debris/2019-10-03/2019-08-28_12-56-53-131/com.huawei.himovie.apk: PUA.Andr.Adware.Ewind-6878615-0 FOUND
/home/joso/MEGA/.debris/2019-10-03/2019-08-28_12-56-53-131/com.bti.tempMeter.apk: PUA.Andr.Trojan.Mobidash-6840972-0 FOUND
/home/joso/MEGA/.debris/2019-10-04/2019-09-13_19-18-51-097/ch.protonmail.android.apk: PUA.Andr.Adware.Domob-6888036-0 FOUND
/home/joso/MEGA/.debris/2019-10-04/2019-09-13_19-18-51-097/com.bti.tempMeter.apk: PUA.Andr.Trojan.Mobidash-6840972-0 FOUND
/home/joso/MEGA/MANUALS/delta_66/Delta_WDM_5_10_00_5057v3 (2017_08_07 19_31_19 UTC).exe: PUA.Win.Packer.Msvcpp-1 FOUND

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 6699353
Engine version: 0.102.1
Scanned directories: 1531
Scanned files: 18306
Infected files: 26
Total errors: 2
Data scanned: 6037.41 MB
Data read: 11919.23 MB (ratio 0.51:1)
Time: 1297.667 sec (21 m 37 s)
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to quarantine or delete files ?

Why? PUA means **potential unwanted application** so a PUA is not a virus. So why would you want to do that?

If you want to get rid of these notices you need to remove the unwanted application. So remove ...

- libreoffice
- firefox

And from the others it seems you  installed some extensions so remove those too:

- opencamera
- lastpass
- protonmail
- tempMeter
- something related to tele2.

I assume you installed those your self in Firefox?

Mind that is also the reason you should not use clamav. Scanning for issues on a Ubuntu machine with rules that apply to Windows will never ever work. Never.

The only correct report you get is by scanning incoming and outgoing files from Windows machines before letting your Windows machines get to or send those files. Basically when you use Ubuntu as a gateway and have Windows desktops in your network.